# How to set data attribute with Jquery

Tags: javascript

I am building a script to create a table of content dynamically, I am setting the dataset attribute on each header and creating a `li` element with the name of this header, but I also need to insert a data attribute on my `li` item, this is not working

```
  function createSummary() {
    const summary = $('#summary')
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        let header = headers[i]
        header.dataset.header = i
        $('<li/>', {
            text: header.innerText,
            // HERE IS WHERER I NEED HELP
            data: {'to': i},
        }).appendTo(summary);
    }
}
```

i also tried to put right before the appendTo `}).data({'to': i}).appendTo(summary);`

Comment: please give one example of such li which you want to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Use the `.attr` method

```
 function createSummary() {
    const summary = $('#summary')
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        let header = headers[i]
        header.dataset.header = i
        $('<li/>', {
            text: header.innerText,
            // HERE IS WHERER I NEED HELP
            //data: {'to': i},
        }).attr('data-to', i).appendTo(summary); //<-- here is the change
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx man, that worked well, but you know how to explain why the `.data()` on the end didn't worked?

Comment: @Dosbodoke No prob. I'm not sure actually. It would seem that using `.data` should have the same effect. Maybe a jquery expert on here might know

Comment: @Dosbodoke Try using the `.data(key, value)` rather than the `.data({object Object})`. Maybe it's something with the formatting of that

Answer (score 0):

You could try using attr() instead. (See [how to add attributes in jquery](https://tutorialdeep.com/knowhow/jquery-add-attribute/))
Also check out [HTML li data-* attribute](https://www.dofactory.com/html/li/data).